# How can I enable sorting for OData service returning dynamic in asp.net mvc web api

Tags: c#, dynamic, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

Here is the code for my controller:

```
public class RegularGrigController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/regulargrig
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return EntityHelper.GetEntities().Select(t => t.ModelName());
        }

        public PageResult<dynamic> Get(string entityName, ODataQueryOptions options)
        {
            var query = EntityHelper.GetQueryable(entityName).Select("new (Id, SysName)"); // Dynamic queryable

            IQueryable results = options.ApplyTo(query); // Exception here

            return new PageResult<dynamic>(results as IEnumerable<dynamic>, Request.GetNextPageLink(), Request.GetInlineCount());
        }
    }
```

When I try to make this call `/api/RegularGrig?entityName=SecurityPrincipal&$orderby=Id`

I receive this exception

```
Type 'System.Object' does not have a property 'Id'
```

So, is there any way to sort/filter dynamic data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me now:

```
public PageResult<dynamic> Get(string entityName)
{
    var query = EntityHelper.GetQueryable(entityName).Select("new (Id, SysName)");
    var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.AddEntity(query.ElementType);
    var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
    var options = new ODataQueryOptions(new ODataQueryContext(model, query.ElementType), this.Request);
    IQueryable results = options.ApplyTo(query);

    return new PageResult<dynamic>(results as IEnumerable<dynamic>, Request.GetNextPageLink(), Request.GetInlineCount());
}
```